# Xamarin Android httpwebrequest, Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, android, post, xamarin, webrequest

I have an android mobile app , and i want to send webrequest to server to post some data, but before posting the data i send an http get request to get some data, and then sending post request , 
first i receive get successfully but when i send the post request it throws bellow exception on this line of my code `requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

the exception is :

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

and here is my get and post request code
GET:

```
public void GetTokenInfo()
        {

            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(_host + "webserver/SesTokInfo", string.Empty));
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (var requestStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(requestStream))
                        {
                            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
                            xDocument.LoadXml(content);
                            XmlElement root = xDocument.DocumentElement;
                            if (IsResponseReturned(root))
                            {
                                GlobalConfig.SessionId = root.GetElementsByTagName("SesInfo")[0].InnerText;
                                GlobalConfig.Token = root.GetElementsByTagName("TokInfo")[0].InnerText;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
```

with this code i get receive my result without any problem, and here is my POST:

```
 public WebResponse PostData(string body, string url)
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = null;
            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(_host + url, string.Empty));
                var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie",
                    GlobalConfig.SessionId);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("_RequestVerificationToken", GlobalConfig.Token);
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
            return webResponse;
        }
```

i have searched and tried ways but i did not get the solution , and plus when i comment the first function, and only run the second function it will work fine but when i run the first and then the second it throws the exception , does anything belong to dispose the stream and web response from first code?
i think using statement is already disposes them.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many ways and read above answers and try them finally i get solved the problem by making the both code like the following ,
 GET one:

```
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(_host + "webserver/SesTokInfo", string.Empty));
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
                        xDocument.LoadXml(content);
                        XmlElement root = xDocument.DocumentElement;
                        if (IsResponseReturned(root))
                        {
                            GlobalConfig.SessionId = root.GetElementsByTagName("SesInfo")[0].InnerText;
                            GlobalConfig.Token = root.GetElementsByTagName("TokInfo")[0].InnerText;

                        }
                    }
                }
```

and POST one:

```
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(_host + url, string.Empty));
                var webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);


                webRequest2.Headers.Add("Cookie",
                    GlobalConfig.SessionId);
                webRequest2.Headers.Add("_RequestVerificationToken", GlobalConfig.Token);
                webRequest2.Method = "POST";
                webRequest2.ContentType = "application/xml";

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                webRequest2.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest2.GetRequestStream());
                writer.Write(bytes);
                webResponse = webRequest2.GetResponse();
```

when i use the request stream inside using block it will still throw the exception but with out using block it will work :)

Answer (score 4):

This may just be a case of making sure to use the correct `using` statements as they properly handle closing the outgoing and incoming streams when appropriate. See the below modified example, this should work for you:

```
public string PostData(string body, string url)
{
    string responseText = null;

    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(_host + url, string.Empty));
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

        webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", GlobalConfig.SessionId);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("_RequestVerificationToken", GlobalConfig.Token);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";

        using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.Write(body);
            }
        }

        var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }

    return responseText;
}
```

Note I have modified the return variable to a string body so that you are not potentially leaving a stream open.

Koda

Comment: many thanks for answering , i used your code but did not get lucky it is still the same , i figured out with using both function asynchronously with httpClient and worked but with this style still getting same exception.

Answer (score 3):

- **is your device/emulator connected to internet?**
- your application has required permission for connect to internet?
- You have to close the request stream  `requestStream.Close()` before call `webRequest.GetResponse()`
- It is required to use `using` for IDisposable objects as in your `GetTokenInfo()` method, else you will have memory overuse problems

I just test you code and **IT WORKS**, this is my full test console application

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace test01
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            PostData("a", "/");
        }

        public static WebResponse PostData(string body, string url)
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = null;
            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://google.it" + url, string.Empty));
                var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie","test");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("_RequestVerificationToken", "test");
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
            return webResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes my device connected to internet,before i get call to GetResponse it throws the exception requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); when i write the bytes , and it is working when i only run second method , but when i first run the first method and then the second method it throws the exception , any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

just to be safe - try removing extra using - instead of

`using (var requestStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(requestStream))`

use

`using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182334.aspx for details.

Comment: thank you for answering , i tried your way now and i got the same exception. :(

Comment: at line call you get the exception?

Comment: the exception was at this line requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); but fixed see bellow answer.